# Не удается передать значения переменных в шаблон smarty

Tags: php, smarty

PHP-код такой

```
$req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tema` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$message); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
$arrayrow[] = $row;
$smarty->assign('uzver_tema',mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `users` where `id`='".$row['id_user']."'")));
$smarty->assign('forum',mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `forum` where `id`='".$row['id_forum']."'")));
$smarty->assign('post',mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `id_tema` = '".$row['id']."' ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1")));
$smarty->assign('kolvo',mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `post` WHERE `id_tema`='".$row['id']."';"),0));
$smarty->assign('arrayrow',$arrayrow);
}
```

Шаблон

```
{foreach from=$arrayrow item=row}
                <table class="blogs_table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="user_blog_avatar" rowspan="3">
{if empty($uzver_tema.avatar)}
<img src="files/avatar/photo.jpg" alt="" title="" width="50" height="50" />
{else}
<img src="files/avatar/{$uzver_tema.avatar}" alt="" title="" width="50" height="50" />
{/if}               
                        </td>
                        <td>
    <a class="user_blog_name">{$uzver_tema.login}</a><span>{$row.time|date_format:"d.m.o в H:i"}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="blog_title_cont">
    <a href="tema.php?id={$row.id}" class="blog_name">{$row.name}</a>
                            <p>{$post.text|truncate:150}</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="br_bt">
                        <td>
        <span>Раздел: <a href="forum.php?id={$forum.id}">{$forum.name}</a></span>
                            <a href="tema.php?id={$row.id}" class="right">Сообщений в теме ({$kolvo})</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
{/foreach}
```

В шаблон не удается передать значения: uzver_tema, forum, post, kolvo. Т.е. если в шаблоне пишу {$kolvo}, то везде выводится одинаковое кол-во сообщений.

Answer (score 1):

Так и должно быть. Последние присвоенные значения перетирают предыдущие.

**Решение**: необходимо полностью сформировать массив данных в контроллере, после чего передать его в отображение.
Дописывайте в `$row` параметры, которые подгружаете в `while`, а потом уже добавляйте его (`$row`) в `$arrayrow`. После этого сможете получить их в цикле шаблона: `{$row.kolvo}`.

Само собой, из цикла контроллера надо убрать все присвоения в шаблон.

*Называть переменные и столбцы БД транслитом - дурной тон. Но это уже вопроса не касается :)*

Comment: Что-то не пойму как дописать. Можете привести пример?

Comment: Да выдергивайте как и выдергивали - это тема отдельного вопроса. Но вместо того, чтобы делать ``assign($kolvo..)``, делайте ``$row['kolvo'] = ..``

Comment: А как дальше этот SQL-запрос продолжить? Мне нужно не только кол-во сообщений определенной темы вытаскивать, но и данные других полей.

Comment: Если сделать так

$req = mysql_query("SELECT `tema`.*, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `post` WHERE `post`.`id_tema`=`tema`.`id`) AS `kolvo`, 
(SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post`.`id_tema`=`tema`.`id`) AS `text` FROM `tema` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$message); 

то запрос не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
$req = mysql_query("SELECT `tema`.*, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `post` WHERE `post`.`id_tema`=`tema`.`id`) AS `kolvo`, 
(SELECT `text` FROM `post` WHERE `post`.`id_tema`=`tema`.`id` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1) AS `text`, 
(SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=`tema`.`id_user`) AS `login`, 
(SELECT `avatar` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=`tema`.`id_user`) AS `avatar` FROM `tema` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$message);
```

Возможно можно как-то и короче сделать.